# Write a function that bundle variables as one

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R

I'm trying to write a function

I have a dataset called wood, this wood dataset set has many columns/Variables

one of the variables is called "STATUS"

in this variable name called STATUS, I have TD, RD, PROCESSING, PENDING, FAILED, ERROR101, ERROR202, INVALID as a row.

what I want is anywhere you see TD, RD, PROCESSING, name them "successful"
and otherwise change the rest to "failed"

Using if else function

Thanks alot

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable, and is likely a violation of your school's academic honesty policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly without a proper reproducible example, but I think you are probably looking for something like this:

Create toy dataframe:

```
STATUS<-c("TD", "RD", "PROCESSING", "PENDING", "FAILED", "ERROR101", "ERROR202", "INVALID")

set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(index=1:8, numerical_1=rnorm(8, 1), numerical_2=sample(1:8), STATUS=STATUS)

  index numerical_1 numerical_2     STATUS
1     1   0.3735462           6         TD
2     2   1.1836433           8         RD
3     3   0.1643714           2 PROCESSING
4     4   2.5952808           1    PENDING
5     5   1.3295078           3     FAILED
6     6   0.1795316           5   ERROR101
7     7   1.4874291           4   ERROR202
8     8   1.7383247           7    INVALID
```

Now reclassify 'STATUS' with base R:

```
df$reclassified_STATUS<-ifelse(df$STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING'), 'successful', 'failed')
df
  index numerical_1 numerical_2     STATUS reclassified_STATUS
1     1   0.7105384           6         TD          successful
2     2   0.7007849           7         RD          successful
3     3   0.5884892           4 PROCESSING          successful
4     4   1.2522234           8    PENDING              failed
5     5   0.1080789           5     FAILED              failed
6     6   1.4356833           2   ERROR101              failed
7     7  -0.2375384           3   ERROR202              failed
8     8   0.7757321           1    INVALID              failed
```

I always feel it is easier to do these operations with dplyr:

```
df%>%
mutate(reclassified_STATUS=ifelse(STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING'),'successful', 'failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Building a test case didn't require a lot of effort. Using `ifelse` and `%in%`seems pretty self-explanatory.

```
STATUS <- scan(text= "TD, RD, PROCESSING, PENDING, FAILED, ERROR101, ERROR202, INVALID", sep=",",what="")
Read 8 items

in_group <- ifelse( STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING'), "successful", 'failed')

 in_group
#[1] "successful" "failed"     "failed"     "failed"     "failed"     "failed"     "failed"    
[8] "failed"
```

Hmmm. The `scan` function doesn't remove whitespace. Does behave properly if you trim the whitespace:

```
STATUS <- trimws (scan(text= "TD, RD, PROCESSING, PENDING, FAILED, ERROR101, ERROR202, INVALID", sep=",",what=""))
Read 8 items
```

---

Another way with logical indexing on the LHS of an assignment:

```
in_group= rep("failed", length(STATUS) )
in_group[STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING')] <- "successful"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ifelse` is not mandatory, here is another frequent solution.

```
c("failed", "successful")[1L + (STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING'))]
#[1] "successful" "successful" "successful" "failed"    
#[5] "failed"     "failed"     "failed"     "failed"
```

#### Explanation

The logical condition returns `FALSE/TRUE` coded internally as `0/1`.

```
STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING')
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Add 1 to this, since in R indices are 1-based. And extract from a vector of possible outcomes.

```
i <- 1L + (STATUS %in% c('TD', 'RD', 'PROCESSING'))
c("failed", "successful")[i]
```